# restrict importing certain modules in python

Tags: python

I am setting this *sys.modules['os']=None* for restricting OS modules in my python notebook. But I want to restrict it by default, is there any file in /bin where I can add this line.
If not, is it possible in RestrictedPython?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that, but you could create a virualenv and delete those modules there

Comment: hmm,, What about restricted-python? Can I do it in restricted-python?

Comment: If you are talking about RPython, then no. RPython is not a Python, sort of speak.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is no true sandboxing in python (you also can try PyPy, they claim that this is achievable all the way down to syscalls via rather nontrivial hooking inside their VM). But what you can try right now is [runpy](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/runpy.html) module from stdlib. It provides a way to run your module inside a restricted environment (yet not a sandbox) via providing this environment explicitly as a dict. Since import statement runs `__import__` function underkeens, this function can be overloaded to not accept certain module names. Though I am not sure how to force Jupiter (or whatever you are using) to run in discussed mode.